# How to implement server side event in distributed environment?

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, rabbitmq

I have two node js server which replicated code for the load balancing there is one Rabbitmq cluster which is commonly used in the project,rabbit mq message consumtion according to the roundrobin manner in the both servers, so messages consume by any one of the server whenever new messages comes in,

Now problem is that I have implemented the SSE (server side event) into the both servers if one user logged in or connect through SSE to anyone of the server and new message comes into the rabbitmq the SSE is called at that time to increse the count, but if user 1 connected to server 1 how server two will update the same total?

```
example -

server 1 => rabbitmq
server 2 => rabbitmq 

(same rabbitmq used by both server only one rabbitmq)

user 1 => server 1 (connected though the SSE) => rabbitmq 

now 

messages comes => rabbitmq gives message to server 2 

no user connected to server 2

message consumed by server 2 => incresing the count

but server 2 dont have any user which is need to update
```

i tryied multiple things but not worked any suggestions happy to take it

Message comes in the rabbit mq

rabbit mq send the messge to any one server

that one server need to update the count for all the server

or atleast send any trigger that he had recevied new message and update the count of that user

Comment: Base asumpion should be that servers are stateless. If you need keep information about state you have to use another application layer like common DB, cache or even filesystem (rabbitMq is not for that). Another thing is that when you emit message to rabbitMQ, you should add context for it like like action type, userId or something that tell thereciever server what it should do with this message.